# How to unhide the recovery partition in ubuntu that is hidden in windows 7?

Tags: partitioning

My recovery drive is hidden in windows 7, and it is not allowed to assign any drive letter to it from storage management of windows, but the partition is shown in storage management of windows as well as in ubuntu. The partition type is 0x37. How could I unhide the partition using either ubuntu or windows?

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to a programme in the Ubuntu Software Centre called GParted, this will let you do most things with the Recovery partition.

It appears to be a powerful tool.